# In Notepad++, how do I remove characters before the fifth | character?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

In Notepad++, I want to remove everything
up to (before) and including the fifth `|` character in a line,
and *keep* everything after the fifth `|` character.

So, the original line would look like:

```
note,:264058|Feb 14 2009 new document|54012|0411|2016|new document|new medicine|book store|784512|Ontario|Canada|80023569
```

How would I get output:

```
new document|new medicine|book store|784512|Ontario|Canada|80023569
```

?

Comment: You would learn about regex

Comment: See http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Comment: do you want to remove everything BEFORE or AFTER fifth `|`??

Answer (score 0):

1. open replace dialog in notepad++ (CTRL+H)
2. for search mode select **regular expression**
3. check the box "wrap around"
4. in "find what" enter `(^|\n)([^|]*\|){5}(.*)` - see [here](https://regex101.com/r/xB9aU7/1) for explanation
5. in "replace to" enter `\1\3`
6. press "replace all"

Comment: @Nghia: If it solves your problem please don't forget to accept it.